# The event filter does not update the entire table

Tags: jsf-2, primefaces

I'm using the event filter to recalculate the totals of the some columns, when filter run new values is calculate ok in the backingBean but not updated in the table. The values is sumaTotal, sumaCUP and sumaCUC and appear at footer of each column.
this is the code:

```
 <p:dataTable emptyMessage="No se encontraron elementos"  widgetVar="tb1"  
                         id="tablaFact" var="item" selection="#{listadoFacturasMB.selectedFactura}" selectionMode="single"  paginator="true" 
                         rows="20" rowKey="#{item.idFactura}" value="#{listadoFacturasMB.facturaUtilList}" filteredValue="#{listadoFacturasMB.filterFacturaUtilList}"> 


                <p:ajax event="rowSelect" update=":frm1:growl :frm1:panelDetallesServicio" oncomplete="servDialog.show()" listener="#{listadoFacturasMB.createPDF}"/>  
                <p:ajax event="rowUnselect"  update=":frm1:growl"/> 
                <p:ajax event="filter" listener="#{listadoFacturasMB.filterListener(filterEvent)}" update="tablaFact"/>

                <f:facet name="header">
                    <h:outputText value="Listado de facturas"/>
                    <p:commandButton id="downloadLink" value="Recargar" icon="ui-icon-refresh" oncomplete="tb1.clearFilters()" update="tablaFact" actionListener="#{listadoFacturasMB.cargarFacturas}"/>                                  
                </f:facet>

                <p:column style="width:10%"  sortBy="#{item.noFactura}" filterBy="#{item.noFactura}" filterMatchMode="contains">
                    <f:facet name="header">
                        <h:outputText value="Nro"/>
                    </f:facet>
                    <h:outputText value="#{item.noFactura}"/>
                </p:column>
                <p:column style="width:10%"  sortBy="#{item.idClientefk}" filterBy="#{item.idClientefk}" filterMatchMode="contains">
                    <f:facet name="header">
                        <h:outputText value="Cliente"/>
                    </f:facet>
                    <h:outputText value="#{item.idClientefk}"/>
                </p:column>
                <p:column style="width:10%"  sortBy="#{item.idPropietariofk.area}" filterBy="#{item.idPropietariofk.area}" filterMatchMode="contains">
                    <f:facet name="header">
                        <h:outputText value="UEB"/>
                    </f:facet>
                    <h:outputText value="#{item.idPropietariofk.area}"/>
                </p:column>           

                <p:column style="width:10%" id="cff3">
                    <f:facet name="header">
                        <h:outputText value='Importe Total'/>
                    </f:facet>
                    <h:outputText value="#{item.importeTotal}"/>
                    <f:facet name="footer">
                        <h:outputText value="#{listadoFacturasMB.sumaTotal}"/>
                    </f:facet>
                </p:column>                  
                <p:column style="width:10%" id="cdd3">
                    <f:facet name="header">
                        <h:outputText value='Importe CUP'/>
                    </f:facet>
                    <h:outputText value="#{item.importeCup}"/>
                    <f:facet name="footer">
                        <h:outputText value="#{listadoFacturasMB.sumaCUP}"/>
                    </f:facet>
                </p:column>                  
                <p:column style="width:10%" id="cjj3">
                    <f:facet name="header">
                        <h:outputText value='Importe CUC'/>
                    </f:facet>
                    <h:outputText value="#{item.importeCuc}"/>
                    <f:facet name="footer">
                        <h:outputText value="#{listadoFacturasMB.sumaCUC}"/>
                    </f:facet>
                </p:column>                      
            </p:dataTable>
```

backing bean:

```
    public void filterListener(FilterEvent filterEvent) {
    try {
        sumaTotal = new BigDecimal(0);
        sumaCUP = new BigDecimal(0);
        sumaCUC = new BigDecimal(0);
        for (int i = 0; i < filterFacturaUtilList.size(); i++) {
            FacturaUtil facturaUtil = filterFacturaUtilList.get(i);
            this.sumaTotal = this.sumaTotal.add(facturaUtil.getImporteTotal());
            this.sumaCUP = this.sumaCUP.add(facturaUtil.getImporteCup());
            this.sumaCUC = this.sumaCUC.add(facturaUtil.getImporteCuc());
        }
        this.sumaTotal = this.sumaTotal.setScale(2, RoundingMode.HALF_UP);
        this.sumaCUP = this.sumaCUP.setScale(2, RoundingMode.HALF_UP);
        this.sumaCUC = this.sumaCUC.setScale(2, RoundingMode.HALF_UP);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        JsfUtil.addErrorMessage(e, "Error: filterListener() " + e.getMessage());
    }
}
```

Comment: I tried to update other component outside of table and work ok, the problem is inside the table, any idea please, maybe I am doing any thing bad.

Comment: What happens if you debug and put the sums in somewhere in the table other than the footer?

Comment: I put the sum in a panelgrid and work ok... inside the table, column or footer no work...